# How do I use MFC CString with the boost string algorithm library

Tags: visual-c++, boost, mfc, boost-range, string-algorithm

*Preliminary note*: string_algo works just fine with `std::wstring` and of course I can (and do) convert the CString object(s) to std::wstring first if and when I need an algorithm from string_algo. It would be really nice though if I could just drop in the CString objects -- integration with existing code would be much easier!

What I want to do:

```
CString in = ...;
const CString out = boost::replace_last_copy(in, L"SEARCH", L"REPLACE");
```

As [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3734103/321013) I tried to additionally include `boost/range/mfc.hpp` to have [Boost.Range adapted to MFC](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/mfc_atl.html). (Although I don't quite get [this header](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/boost/range/mfc.hpp) as looking at it it seems it doesn't do anything for CString, only for the collection classes.)

Boost 1.44.0 with Visual Studio 2005

Test code looks like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/range/mfc.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

void f(CString const& input) {
    CString out = boost::replace_last_copy(input, L"FROM", L"TO");
    std::wcout << out << "\n";
}
```

The error I get looks like this:

```
1>c:\programme\boost_library-1_44_0\boost\algorithm\string\detail\find_format_store.hpp(77) : error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'boost::range_const_iterator<C>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            C=const CString
1>        ]
1>        c:\programme\boost_library-1_44_0\boost\algorithm\string\detail\find_format.hpp(139) : see reference to function template instantiation 'bool boost::algorithm::detail::check_find_result<const InputT,const FindResultT>(InputT &,FindResultT &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            InputT=CString,
1>            FindResultT=boost::iterator_range<const wchar_t *>
1>        ]
1>        c:\programme\boost_library-1_44_0\boost\algorithm\string\find_format.hpp(113) : see reference to function template instantiation 'InputT boost::algorithm::detail::find_format_copy_impl<SequenceT,FormatterT,boost::iterator_range<IteratorT>>(const InputT &,FormatterT,const FindResultT &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            InputT=CString,
1>            SequenceT=CString,
1>            FormatterT=boost::algorithm::detail::const_formatF<boost::iterator_range<const wchar_t *>>,
1>            IteratorT=const wchar_t *,
1>            FindResultT=boost::iterator_range<const wchar_t *>
1>        ]
1>        c:\programme\boost_library-1_44_0\boost\algorithm\string\replace.hpp(314) : see reference to function template instantiation 'SequenceT boost::algorithm::find_format_copy<SequenceT,boost::algorithm::detail::last_finderF<SearchIteratorT,PredicateT>,boost::algorithm::detail::const_formatF<RangeT>>(const SequenceT &,FinderT,FormatterT)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            SequenceT=CString,
1>            SearchIteratorT=const wchar_t *,
1>            PredicateT=boost::algorithm::is_equal,
1>            RangeT=boost::iterator_range<const wchar_t *>,
1>            FinderT=boost::algorithm::detail::last_finderF<const wchar_t *,boost::algorithm::is_equal>,
1>            FormatterT=boost::algorithm::detail::const_formatF<boost::iterator_range<const wchar_t *>>
1>        ]
1>        ....\mytest.cpp(10) : see reference to function template instantiation 'SequenceT boost::algorithm::replace_last_copy<CString,const wchar_t[5],const wchar_t[3]>(const SequenceT &,Range1T (&),Range2T (&))' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            SequenceT=CString,
1>            Range1T=const wchar_t [5],
1>            Range2T=const wchar_t [3]
1>        ]
1>c:\programme\boost_library-1_44_0\boost\algorithm\string\detail\find_format_store.hpp(78) : error C3203: 'type' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'IteratorT', expected a real type
1>c:\programme\boost_library-1_44_0\boost\algorithm\string\detail\find_format.hpp(121) : error C2780: 'void boost::algorithm::detail::insert(InputT &,InputT::iterator,const InsertT &)' : expects 3 arguments - 4 provided
1>        c:\programme\boost_library-1_44_0\boost\algorithm\string\detail\sequence.hpp(39) : see declaration of 'boost::algorithm::detail::insert'
1>        c:\programme\boost_library-1_44_0\boost\algorithm\string\detail\find_format.hpp(144) : see reference to function template instantiation 'InputT boost::algorithm::detail::find_format_copy_impl2<InputT,FormatterT,FindResultT,boost::iterator_range<IteratorT>>(const InputT &,FormatterT,const FindResultT &,const FormatResultT &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            InputT=CString,
1>            FormatterT=boost::algorithm::detail::const_formatF<boost::iterator_range<const wchar_t *>>,
1>            FindResultT=boost::iterator_range<const wchar_t *>,
1>            IteratorT=const wchar_t *,
1>            FormatResultT=boost::iterator_range<const wchar_t *>
1>        ]
1>c:\programme\boost_library-1_44_0\boost\algorithm\string\detail\find_format.hpp(121) : error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'void boost::algorithm::detail::insert(InputT &,InputT::iterator,ForwardIteratorT,ForwardIteratorT)'
1>        With the following template arguments:
1>        'CString'
1>        'const wchar_t *'
1>c:\programme\boost_library-1_44_0\boost\algorithm\string\detail\find_format.hpp(123) : error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'void boost::algorithm::detail::insert(InputT &,InputT::iterator,const InsertT &)'
1>        With the following template arguments:
1>        'CString'
1>        'boost::iterator_range<IteratorT>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            IteratorT=const wchar_t *
1>        ]
1>c:\programme\boost_library-1_44_0\boost\algorithm\string\detail\find_format.hpp(123) : error C2780: 'void boost::algorithm::detail::insert(InputT &,InputT::iterator,ForwardIteratorT,ForwardIteratorT)' : expects 4 arguments - 3 provided
1>        c:\programme\boost_library-1_44_0\boost\algorithm\string\detail\sequence.hpp(29) : see declaration of 'boost::algorithm::detail::insert'
1>c:\programme\boost_library-1_44_0\boost\algorithm\string\detail\find_format.hpp(125) : error C2780: 'void boost::algorithm::detail::insert(InputT &,InputT::iterator,const InsertT &)' : expects 3 arguments - 4 provided
1>        c:\programme\boost_library-1_44_0\boost\algorithm\string\detail\sequence.hpp(39) : see declaration of 'boost::algorithm::detail::insert'
1>c:\programme\boost_library-1_44_0\boost\algorithm\string\detail\find_format.hpp(125) : error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'void boost::algorithm::detail::insert(InputT &,InputT::iterator,ForwardIteratorT,ForwardIteratorT)'
1>        With the following template arguments:
1>        'CString'
1>        'const wchar_t *'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `CString` with `CStringW`, in case `CString` is mapped to `CStringA`.

What about exact error code, at which line in header? Can you try replacing the same error in local code?

Comment: It was very definitely a UNICODE build, so `CStringW`. The full test code is in the question.  (modulo a mostly empty `main`)

Comment: What if you explicity typecast to LPCWSTR, or use GetString, or pass a non-const CString object?